# Oracle | Update Long type | Error: Illegal use of LONG datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, long-integer

How to rectify issue on UPDATE?

Following is related data and error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE JOB_STATUS 
SET STATUS ='FAILED' ,ENDDATE=sysdate, REMARKS = 'Error' 
WHERE ID = 30
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Following is table structure:

```
ID  LONG
STARTDATE   TIMESTAMP(6)
ENDDATE TIMESTAMP(6)
STATUS  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
REMARKS VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
JOBID   NUMBER(38,0)
```

Not able to find answers in related questions. Not sure whether i need to modify table datatype but when i try to modify it says remove data first.

Comment: Yes , you have to change the datatype. Long is not a valid datatype for an id column. Its not similar to java. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm. and to change datatype of a column prerequisite is the column should be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if ID is Primary Key -  it should not be LONG.**

The LONG column has limitations - You can use LONG columns in SELECT lists, SET clauses of UPDATE statements, and VALUES clauses of INSERT statements.

there is larger list where it cannot be used! including

- LONG columns cannot appear in WHERE clauses or in integrity constraints (except that they can appear in NULL and NOT NULL constraints).

see for list https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831